# Does it harm if I send many interrupt to non-sleeping Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread that I make it sleep (using Thread.sleep(60000) ) for some time when waiting for some task to execute. Once there a request arrived, I wake it up from another thread by calling (t.inerrupt).

I can see it it works fine so far. If I send t.inerrupt when Thread in a sleep, it wake up. 
However, what if the process is not sleeping (doing actual work), would calling t.inerrupt have any effect on the thread?

Comment: It gets very grouchy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt%28%29)

> If none of the previous conditions hold *[ie. thread is not blocked or sleeping]* then this thread's interrupt status will be set.

So only a flag is set.

Comment: @user836026 You can get its value with `Thread#isInterrupted()`. So if you need to change behaviour, you can check the flag and take appropriate actions.